# '>' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm creating a CRUD application that displays activities available on or after today;  I'm working through the filtering mechanism on displaying these activities, however I'm having a nightmare trying to only show the activities that are on/after today.

I'm getting the below error when I try to use the '>=' operand, however it's giving me the following error:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'datetime.date'
```

Below is my views.py for the comparison:

```
today= date.today()
available_activities = Activity.objects.filter(available = True).values()
activities = available_activities.filter(date > today).values()
activities= available_activities.order_by('date','start_time')
```

Below is a screenshot of the error traceback also, to show the data format for the data in the DB also.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with the [**`__gt`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) so:

```
today = date.today()
available_activities = Activity.objects.filter(
    available=True, date__gt=today
).order_by('date', 'start_time')
```